# Regular expression to match a range 0-255 without ^ and $

Tags: regex, regular-language

Is there a way to match a range of numbers(0-255) without the `^` and `$`?

### Matched numbers

- 1
- 12
- 123

### Not matched numbers

- 1234
- 555

Comment: What do you mean under `without the ^ and $`?

Comment: Unless your engine anchor the complete expression, you will need some kind of delimiter that prevents parts of invalid numbers to be matched. There are many workarounds, but why not just use `^` and `$`?

Comment: @zhiwei this question may qualify for re-opening if you edit your question to ask for patterns that permit lookarounds.  Otherwise, the duplicate link is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead and lookbehind to match **only** 1-3 digits.

```
(?<!\d)(?:[1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))(?!\d)
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/K5c2kZ/4)

Answer (score 1):

Not using anchor characters, BrightOne was wise to integrate lookarounds for numeric characters.  However, the pattern isn't fully refined.  To optimize the pattern for speed and maintain accuracy:

1. Use quantifiers on consecutive duplicate characters.
2. Organize the alternatives not in sequential order but with quickest mis-matches first.
3. Avoid non-essential capture (or non-capture) groups. (despite seeming logical to condense the "two hundreds" portion of the pattern)

This is my suggested pattern: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gl0Xet/2))

```
/(?<!\d)(?:1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|[1-9]?\d|25[0-5])(?!\d)/  #3526 steps
```

(Brightone's pattern resolves in **5155 steps**)
(treesongs' second pattern resolves in **5184 steps**)  *at time of posting, the first pattern was inaccurate)

Comment: That's a well-crafted regex. Nice work @mickmackusa! This should be an accepted answer. *"Mastering Regular Expressions" didn't help me at all*

Comment: @BrightOne  See the guy who closed this question?  That is who I learn the most from.  I recommend that if you want to learn some wicket-awesome techniques just follow his posts on SO.  There are certainly other highly skilled posters who are just as worthy of watching -- you will know them when you see them.  Hang out on SO, you will learn HEAPS!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out :)